# Handling forms that are on every page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

The way I made it work is create a dedicated controller that handles my forms that repeat on multiple pages i.e. `somedomain.com/form/callmeback/` and so far so good. However, once the validator has done its thing I need to either return to the page from which the form was submitted, with a list of errors to display or send the message and then return to the originating form page with a success message.

What would be the "best" way to accomplish that?

So far my thoughts are lingering on using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` or a hidden field with a `current_url()` as its value, and then just do `header('Location:'.$_POST['ref'])` but that would not allow me to post back validation errors.

**[EDIT]**

In the end I've solved my problem using codeIgniter session flash data functionality

```
//redirect back to source
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], base_url()) !== false) {
        //do form handling stuff here
        $this->session->set_flashdata('callmeback_errors', validation_errors());
        header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    } else {
        //invalid referer, do nothing say nothing, pretend the page doesn't exist
        show_404();
    }
```

thanks for your ideas :)

Comment: Serialize your errors to the session and then remove them on the next request like "flash" message. Ive done similar before with Symfony.

Comment: @prodigitalson that is one possibility looking how CI neatly has flashdata functionality

Comment: Did you consider Ajax for this?  Your forms could send an Ajax request and return errors or messages.

Comment: @prodigitalson could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Better use ajax on this case

Answer (score 1):

Flash session is a good idea but i m not sure if it will be working properly with `validation_errors()` function,

but i have a different thought, what about instead of dedicated controller and dedicated helper that do the same functionality including so you wont have to change the controller and just send the POST array to helper function, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your errors to the session and then remove them on the next request like "flash" message. Ive done similar before with Symfony.